# Codeigniter. One __constructor to several controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have some controllers, where __constructor is similar in every of it. How to avoid copy-paste of similar code and write it in a one place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **controller** lets say `ParentController` and extends it with **base controller** then add **__contructor** in that.
Now in all of your **controllers** where you want this constructor just extend your **controllers** with the created controller `ParentController`.

**ParentController.php**:

```
class ParentController extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //your constructor code here..
    }
}
```

Now the controllers in which you want the same constructor can be extended from **ParentController** :
**ClassA.php**

```
class ClassA extends ParentController {
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    //your first controller
}
```

**ClassB.php**

```
class ClassB extends ParentController{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    //Your second controller
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it will help me. Think you :)

Comment: If that helped you mark it as answer to help others. Glad to help you :)

Comment: By the way this is one of the most common benefits of Object Oriented Paradigm .

Answer (score 0):

Best place for ParentController.php would be application/core/ folder.